# Can't reach block number

Tags: web3js, ether, etherscan

I have integrate the getwallet and version 1.6.7 . Now etherscan.io's blocknumber is 4437327 . but my wallet show 4370000 only this blocknumber . it is not increase. still i am waiting for this block count . Please guide me why it is happen? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a fork on block 4370000 (happened on October 16). See announcement at the Ethereum Foundation blog [Byzantium HF Announcement](https://blog.ethereum.org/2017/10/12/byzantium-hf-announcement/).

You should have upgraded to geth v1.7.2. You should not be able to synchronize with previous version.